# How to change only line shape color in vba powerpoint

Tags: vba, colors, powerpoint, lines, shapes

I have task to make colour fill in Powerpoint VBA. When I select lines and boxes I want to change lines only and leave the boxes colour. Is there a way to change only private shapes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The below code will change all the line colours in slide 2 to red in Powerpoint 2007:

```
Public Sub ChangeLineColours()

Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes '<~~ Change '2' to whichever slide you want to loop through
    If shp.Type = msoLine Then
        shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I add a colored border to an image?

Comment: @Daxtrox Hi, please start a new question with what you are trying to achieve :).